# Need help figuring out progress bar solution

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm making a very basic app using web technologies (html,css, jquery mobile).

The app just allows me to create goals and save them to a listview a `<li>` element. For each `<li>` that has a goal, I also have a div that will be used to display an image of a progress bar set to 0%.

So lets say I've added 10 goals, that means there will be 10 `<li>` elements displaying the goal I set such as "Walk the dog" or whatever, When I select which goal I want to work on, I will do so by clicking or pressing (if using on a phone), the `<li>` with the goal I want to work on and then I will be taken to the next screen (page) which will have a slider allowing me to select how much of the goal I've completed and I can select between 0%, 50% or 100% with the slider.

I need to be able to target the `<li>` with the current goal I'm working on to change the style of the div to display an image that will show a progress bar matching what percentage I have completed 0%, 50%, or 100%. What is a simple way to do this?

Comment: When you go to the 'next screen' are they actually leaving the page? Are you saving their progress percentage to a database, or just keeping it for that session? Can you share some of the relevant code.

Comment: Unfortunately I have the code on another machine. Yes, I would also like goal progress to be saved. I was thinking of using html5 local storage but I'm not sure if that'll be good enough. I'm not sure what solution is suitable when it will ultimately be a basic phone app wrapped with phone gap.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this will surely help you...

https://github.com/tolis-e/jQuery-Mobile-Progress-Bar-with-Percentage